# When does Phoenix's Socket.js fire the onConnError vs the onError callbacks?

Tags: javascript, websocket, phoenix-framework

I'm writing an application that uses the Phoenix channels and phoenix's socket.js. I want to handle errors when the websocket can't connect (spotty Internet connection, etc.) and show an appropriate message.

Looking at the socket.js source code, there are two possible ways to register for errors on the Socket object. The first is

```
socket.onConnError(callback)
```

and the second is

```
socket.onError(callback)
```

I can trigger onError to be called by stopping the Phoenix server and trying to call `socket.connect()` in a browser. I can't seem to get `socket.onConnError` to fire though - when is it used? What are the differences between these two events/callbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onConnError` is not a way to register a callback for an error. `onConnError` is used to *trigger* an error. Calling `onConnError` will, in addition to some other things, [call all the `onError` callbacks with the specified error message](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/71b1c2e85960d4124cec86bc287956ed6c69239a/assets/js/phoenix.js#L681). It's [called by the `Socket` class itself](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/71b1c2e85960d4124cec86bc287956ed6c69239a/assets/js/phoenix.js#L635) on any errors thrown by the connection object.

Answer (score 0):

Looking *more* closely at the source code, looks like onConnError is used internally for actually triggering the onError callbacks that the user has registered.

Short answer: Use `socket.onError`.